# Laravel route() returns wrong url for localhost

Tags: php, laravel, routes, browser-sync

So I'm at lost as to why laravel's global function `route()` generate a wrong URL when used in localhost.

I used it like so `route('home:index');` and the generated route is `//localhost:3010/home` instead of `https://localhost:3010/home`

I tested both URL in browser and only 2nd one works. The firs one shows `Your File Was Not Found` error page.

I define the route as follows:

```php
Route::group(['as' => 'home:', 'prefix' => 'home', 'namespace' => 'Home'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
    // other routes here.
});
```

After further investigation, this only happens in localhost when I use browser-sync. Is there a way to configure browser-sync or laravel to return correct route?

P/S : As additional info, even with route generated as `//localhost:3010/home` laravel still manage to redirect it to the right page. But when I tried creating `new URL('//localhost:3010/home')` in JS it returned as invalid URL.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Rather than specifying `route('home/index')` give it a name and use in route

Comment: Please provide code of route file and related code with the issue so that to identify the issue.

Comment: As @AnkitJindal alludes to, you probably want to define your route like `Route::get('home/index', "SomeController@someAction")->name('home');` then call `route('home')` or use `url('home/index')`

Comment: I did define the route that way @WesleySmith

Comment: Cool, but you're calling `route('home/index');` not `route('home')`

Comment: Then call it that way in which you have named.

Comment: @WesleySmith I updated the post with the way the route is setup.

Comment: Actually, per your edit, you did not define the route that way, there is no `->name('home')` on that route

Comment: `'namespace'  => 'Home'` Is not what we're referring to, please recheck the comment above

Comment: @WesleySmith oh sorry, I didn't realise I placed the route() wrongly. Updated, I actually tested it with `route('home:index')` i did used named route. Im really sorry for the wrong info. as for `name()` yes I didn't use `->name()` because I set the route name using `as => []`

Comment: This only happens with localhost. If i use valet's route with `.test` TLD, it works as expected. the URL is generated with `HTTPS::` prefix but it didn't when I used localhost.

Comment: Hmm, Ive never used that syntax myself, that said the docs show an example like:

`'as' => 'home::'` then `'as' => 'index'` and called like `route('home::index")` not sure if that double `:` matters, but thats what the example uses

Comment: Oddly, that syntax using 'as' isnt mentioned at all in the latest docs for v 8.x, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing though it is in some older versions

Comment: Actually, its not mentioned in any docs after v5.2

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['as' => 'home:', 'prefix' => 'home', 'namespace' => 'Home'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
    // other routes here.
});
```

Use above route as `route('index')` or else use it as `url('/')`